# Selecting one column of the Nth row from a refernced table in the select list

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have two tables: cross_section and layer.

Every cross section has multiple layers, which in turn have a position and a summary column. The positions (integer) are used to order each cross section's layers, but do not have to be consecutive (e.g. 10, 20, 40).

I need to extend the query to the cross_section table to include summaries of each cross section's layers (fixed number > 1) that preserves the order defined by the position attribute.

Most of the SQL gets generated automatically; I can only add to the select list extra elements containing subqueries.
This is what the automatically generated SQL looks like:

```
select cs.*, [first layer summary], [second layer summary]... from cross_section cs;
```

I have tried multiple different approaches, but none worked as expected (maybe this is simply not possible).

My current non-working statment looks like this:

```
---------------generated------------------------------------------
select cs.*,
---------------partial statment for clumn one---------------------
    (select summary 
    from (select summary, l.cs_id 
         from layer l order by layer_position)
    where cross_section.id like cs_id and rownum=1) layer_summary_1,
---------------partial statment for clumn two---------------------
    (select summary 
    from (select summary, l.cs_id 
         from layer l order by layer_position)
    where cross_section.id like cs_id and rownum=2) layer_summary_2
---------------generated------------------------------------------
from cross_section cs;
```

Right now, anything other than the first position comes back as null.

**Edit:**
Example output, as requested:

```
CSID,   Stuff from cross section,   layer_summary_1,    layer_summary_2
12345,  ...,                        stuff               (null)
```

Comment: share sample and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this clause: `rownum=2`.

The `rownum` pseudo-column enumerates rows in the generated result set. So there is a `rownum = 1` which returns one row; this is why you found the first position comes back as expected. But there can never be `rownum = 2`. ( `rownum <= 2` returns two rows, because there is a row where `rownum = 1` .)

The solution is simple: use the analytic `row_number()` function in your subqueries which you can reference in the main WHERE clause:

```
---------------generated------------------------------------------
select cs.*,
---------------partial statment for clumn one---------------------
    (select summary 
    from (select summary, l.cs_id  
                 , row_number() over (order by layer_position) as rn 
         from layer l order by layer_position)
    where cross_section.id like cs_id and rn=2)
---------------partial statment for clumn two---------------------
    (select summary 
    from (select summary, l.cs_id 
                 , row_number() over (order by layer_position) as rn 
         from layer l order by layer_position)
    where cross_section.id like cs_id and rn=2)
---------------generated------------------------------------------
from cross_section cs;
```

Your question isn't clear about the data or business logic, so the above may produce incorrect results. If so, you need to tweak the window clause by adding PARTITION BY criteria.  Such as:

```
  , row_number() over (partition by cs_id order by layer_position) as rn
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. As you suspected, I needed to tweak the window clause.